# Replace null values in SQL Pivot Query

Tags: sql-server, sqlite

I have a stored procedure accepts date and month as parameter which results monthly attendance sheet. In order handle null values I want to replace null values to 'Zero'.

Stored Procedure

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[sps_AttendanceShowModified] @mon int, @year int
As begin DECLARE @cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)=''; DECLARE @query AS
NVARCHAR(MAX)='';

set @query =  'SELECT * from  (
     select  e.Name,a.WorkHours,DAY(a.AttendaceDate) AS d1 from  Attendace a,employee e where e.EmpID=a.EmpID and
MONTH(a.AttendaceDate)= ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @mon)+ ' AND
YEAR(a.AttendaceDate)= ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @year)+ ' ) src pivot 
(
    max(WorkHours) for d1 in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30])
) piv'

execute(@query) end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your `SELECT *` to handle `null` using `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` like following.

`SELECT name,COALESCE([1],0) AS [1],COALESCE([2],0) AS [2] ....` other columns

If you want `'Zero'` to appear, in that case you need to use `CAST` or `CONVERT` before applying `COALESCE` like following.

```
COALESCE(cast([1] as varchar),'Zero') as [1]
```

Comment: thanks dude!, and will you  show me  sum of these [1]+[2]....+[30] columns